# Can you identify these parts? Sliding brick and plate with a groove

Tags: part-identification

Please help me identify these LEGO parts - I'm trying to build them.[image: Can you identify these parts?]

Comment: You can see the original video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLquE3OtUqkrS_-kdpBk8Xzdbzggfskzxu&v=DZcMTnmFbo4

Answer (score 8):

The plate is probably a [Plate 1X8 With Rail](http://brickset.com/parts/451002) or maybe [Plate 1X2 With Slide](http://brickset.com/parts/4107761)

The Brick is a [Sliding Piece 1X4](http://brickset.com/parts/265326)

Comment: Thanks!   You're awesome!  I hope you're having a nice day :)